Post adaptive card and wait for a response to multiples users simultaneously
I created an automatic flow that gets the list of users from a group of teams and sends an adaptive card with the option “Post adaptive card and wait for a response”, however, this is sent to all users as a chain and not simultaneously, even if I have enabled the “Concurrency Control” in settings for more than 20 users. I need this to be sent simultaneously to all users on the list.Does anyone know how to do this?
I am trying to send a course to multiple users simultaneously via microsoft teams and get an automatic course completion confirmation response.

Have a look at ASSIGN ADAPTIVE CARD TO MULTIPLE TEAMS USERS

Multiple flows is the way to go. Depending on how many people you need to send to, limits may kick in though.
